# Send notifcation to open wallet

Tags: firebase, push-notification, wallet

I would like to send a firebase notification to mobile device, and after opening this notification i would like to open my wallet.

is it possible to do this with firebase or with an apple notification system.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the wallet is? Is it another app from another company or is it one of your personal apps? Is this for Android, iOS, Flutter, Web? The more details you provide, the more we may be able to help point you in the right direction

Comment: @AlexanderN. wallet is an app from apple it is for ios